# Error: Input must be a vector, not a <spei> object

Tags: r, lapply

I have a large panel data with provinces for each year-month. I would like to run a function through a list of data frames (that I create based on this initial data frame) in order to get a new column for each of them with the input of this function. However, when I run the code, I continue to get an error. Here is the code:

```
adm1    year month prov_code mean_temperaturec province_name avgpreci longitude latitude PET[,"PET_tho"]
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>           <dbl>
1 TUR034  1978     1 TR100                  5.61 Istanbul        170.        28.8     41.2            10.3
2 TUR034  1978     2 TR100                  7.48 Istanbul         88         28.8     41.2            15.8
3 TUR034  1978     3 TR100                  8.55 Istanbul         71         28.8     41.2            24.1
4 TUR034  1978     4 TR100                 11.6  Istanbul         88.7       28.8     41.2            41.4
5 TUR034  1978     5 TR100                 16.6  Istanbul         33.2       28.8     41.2            80.5
6 TUR034  1978     6 TR100                 20.8  Istanbul          5.30      28.8     41.2           115. 
# ... with 2 more variables: wbal <dbl[,1]>, SPEI <dbl>

data4spei.s <- split(dataSPEI, dataSPEI$prov_code)

spei_rows <- lapply(data4spei.s, function(x) {
  x$SPEI <- spei(x$wbal, 12, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(x)
})
```

> Error in `stop_vctrs()`: ! Input must be a vector, not a 
> object. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

For a different function the code worked properly and I could get the columns. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred?

Comment: Hello @jpsmith, thanks for the answer. Yes, this is what I got
{> rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_scalar_type>
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Input must be a vector, not a <spei> object.
Backtrace:
  1. base::lapply(...)
  9. vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(`<fn>`(`<spei>`), "")
 10. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(msg, "vctrs_error_scalar_type", actual = x)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/vctrs_error_scalar_type>
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Input must be a vector, not a <spei> object.}